# Codes in how to upload pdf file using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, file-upload

I don't know the codes in how to upload the PDF file in PHP. Can I have a sample codes for it with a modified upload size? Any help is appreciated. Is it possible to save it to database and can delete it? Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a lot of tutorials out there. This **[tutorial](https://www.codexworld.com/php-file-upload/)** worked for me.

**Step 1 –  A basic user interface to select file**

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" name="file" size="50" />

<br />

<input type="submit" value="Upload" />

</form>
```

**Step 2 – Uploading file to server PHP script**

```
<?php

 $targetfolder = "testupload/";

 $targetfolder = $targetfolder . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']) ;

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetfolder))

 {

 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " is uploaded";

 }

 else {

 echo "Problem uploading file";

 }

 ?>
```

**Limiting the file types / Uploading images with PHP script**

```
<?php

 $targetfolder = "testupload/";

 $targetfolder = $targetfolder . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']) ;

 $ok=1;

$file_type=$_FILES['file']['type'];

if ($file_type=="application/pdf" || $file_type=="image/gif" || $file_type=="image/jpeg") {

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetfolder))

 {

 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " is uploaded";

 }

 else {

 echo "Problem uploading file";

 }

}

else {

 echo "You may only upload PDFs, JPEGs or GIF files.<br>";

}

?>
```