# How do I use php to upload .pdf and .docx file along with images from a form

Tags: php, upload

I have an e library website where the admin is supposed to upload books to the server along with other information and the cover art of the book which is usually in .jpeg or .jpg, how do I do it? Here is my code below

```
    <?php

require_once("db.php");
$book_title = $book_author = $book_category = $isbn_no = $purchase_date = $edition = $pages = $publisher = $book_link = $book_internal = $cover_art = '';

if(isset($_POST['upload_books'])) {


    $file = $_FILES["book_internal"]; //getting user uploaded file

    move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], "uploads/books" .$file["name"]); //save file to upload folder




$book_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['book_title']);
$book_author = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['book_author']);
$book_category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['book_category']);
$isbn_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['isbn_no']);
$purchase_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['purchase_date']);
$edition = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['edition']);
$pages = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pages']);
$publisher = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['publisher']);
$book_link = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['book_link']);
$book_internal = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['book_internal']);
$cover_art = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['cover_art']);


    $sql = "INSERT INTO books (book_title, book_author, book_category, isbn_no, purchase_date, edition, pages, publisher, book_link, book_internal, cover_art)
    VALUES ('$book_title', '$book_author', '$book_category', '$isbn_no', '$purchase_date', '$edition', '$pages', '$publisher', '$book_link', '$book_internal', '$cover_art')";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if($result) {
        header("location: upload-books.php");
        echo "Upload successful!";

    }
    else {
        echo "Error:".mysqli_error($conn);
    }


}

 ?>
```

Comment: Are you experiencing problems? Incidentally your app is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: This little piece of code has multiple problems and lot of unnecessary code. If you have been following some tutorial I recommend to find a better one.

Comment: Where is the form for this?

Comment: You can't use a header *and* echo.

Comment: Thanks Funk Forty niner

Answer (score 0):

[Codes in how to upload pdf file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320735/codes-in-how-to-upload-pdf-file-using-php][1])

You upload them in the same way you upload images.

PS: I can recommend you this code to be sure there are no duplicates in yor folder files names:

```
    $uploadStatus = 1;
    $uploadedFile = '';
    if (!empty($_FILES["img1"]["name"]))
    {
        $fileName = basename($_FILES["img1"]["name"]);
        $filenamewithoutextension = strtolower(pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_FILENAME));
        $fileType = strtolower(pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        $filename_to_store = $filenamewithoutextension. '_' .uniqid(). '.' .$fileType;

        $allowTypes = array(
            'jpg',
            'png',
            'jpeg'
        );
        if (in_array($fileType, $allowTypes))
        {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img1"]["tmp_name"], $uploadDir.$filename_to_store))
            {
                $uploadedFile = $filename_to_store;
            }
            else
            {
                $uploadStatus = 0;
                $response['message'] = 'Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $uploadStatus = 0;
            $response['message'] = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG & PNG files are allowed.';
        }
    }
    if($uploadStatus==1)
    { //insert Them into you table }
```

Comment: But I'm also trying to upload pdf files

Comment: I know, that's why I gave you the link. The code is identical